# super().__init__ overwrites an attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, keras, super

I'm setting an attribute in a subclass initialiser, which seems to be overwritten by a call to `super().__init__`.

```
from keras.layers import GRU, wrappers


class Dummy(wrappers.Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, layer, **kwargs):
        self.stateful = True
        print(self.stateful)
        super().__init__(layer, **kwargs)
        print(self.stateful)

In [3]: dummy = Dummy(GRU(64, stateful=True))
True
False
In [4]: dummy.stateful
Out[4]: False
```

I would assume something in `wrappers.Wrapper` overwrites the attribute, but a built-in wrapper subclass [`Bidirectional`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/628cf08be1a3f8a4547f6321677470d52b725819/keras/layers/wrappers.py#L256) with an almost identical superclass init call (I basically followed the pattern from this subclass in my implementation)

```
class Bidirectional(Wrapper):

    def __init__(self, layer, merge_mode='concat', weights=None, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.stateful = layer.stateful
        ...
        super(Bidirectional, self).__init__(layer, **kwargs)
```

doesn't demonstrate this behaviour

```
In [6]: bidir = wrappers.Bidirectional(GRU(64, stateful=True))

In [7]: bidir.stateful
Out[7]: True
```

I can't wrap my head around this. I'm using Keras 2.1.3 under Python 3.6.

P.S.

I've already tried replacing `super().__init__(layer, **kwargs)` with `super(Dummy, self).__init__(layer, **kwargs)` in my subclass to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong version of the `Bidirectional` source code. The version you're looking at seems to be [this one](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c7efb4e30f914555954f1d07c585c7a2ff9150de/keras/layers/wrappers.py), from three days ago. I believe that version has the same bug your code has.

The code in what I believe is the [latest release](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.1.3/keras/layers/wrappers.py#L248) calls `super().__init__` at the *start* of its own `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, layer, merge_mode='concat', weights=None, **kwargs):
    super(Bidirectional, self).__init__(layer, **kwargs)
    ...
```

That way, its actions happen after the ancestor constructors' actions, and its assignment of `self.stateful` overrides its ancestors.

Comment: I followed the link from [https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/). Seems like, they haven't fixed the link in the docs. I guess, I should file a documentation patch.